# MS Access update query that calls a function doesn't return anything/update a field

Tags: sql, vba, function, ms-access

I have a text field `Ran` and I want to be able to update the field `RanKeyNo5` (update query) with the numeric equivalent (2 digits) for a specified number of letters as they occur in the `Ran` field, i.e. the first 5 letters of the alphabet in the order that they occur in `Ran`.

For example, if `Ran` contains `BFHCIEALGJDK`, the answer would be `0203050104`.

I put message boxes in the code to monitor the values, and it seemed to work, but the table doesn't get updated.

Query, 'update to':

```sql
KeyNo([Ran],5)
```

```vb
Public Function KeyNo(myStr As String, intLen As Integer) As String
Dim RandomString As String, strLetter As String, PosNo As Integer, LetSelect As String, LetNo As String, Count As Integer

RandomString = "00"
PosNo = 1
Count = Len(myStr)

'MsgBox myStr

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Count

    LetSelect = Mid(myStr, PosNo, 1)

    If LetSelect = "A" Then
        LetNo = "01"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "B" Then
        LetNo = "02"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "C" Then
        LetNo = "03"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "D" Then
        LetNo = "04"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "E" Then
        LetNo = "05"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "F" Then
        LetNo = "06"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "G" Then
        LetNo = "07"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "H" Then
        LetNo = "08"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "I" Then
        LetNo = "09"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "J" Then
        LetNo = "10"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "K" Then
        LetNo = "11"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "L" Then
        LetNo = "12"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "M" Then
        LetNo = "13"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "N" Then
        LetNo = "14"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "O" Then
        LetNo = "15"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "P" Then
        LetNo = "16"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "Q" Then
        LetNo = "17"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "R" Then
        LetNo = "18"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "S" Then
        LetNo = "19"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "T" Then
        LetNo = "20"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "U" Then
        LetNo = "21"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "V" Then
        LetNo = "22"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "W" Then
        LetNo = "23"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "X" Then
        LetNo = "24"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "Y" Then
        LetNo = "25"
    ElseIf LetSelect = "Z" Then
        LetNo = "26"
    End If

    If Val(LetNo) <= intLen Then
        RandomString = RandomString & LetNo
'        MsgBox RandomString
    End If

    PosNo = PosNo + 1
Next

RandomString = Mid(RandomString, 3, intLen * 2)

End Function
```

Comment: Discover [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement) to replace ElseIf and especially [Asc](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/asc-function) function to make it obsolete here!

Answer (score 3):

It returns nothing because function is not set to return anything. Last line should be:

`KeyNo = Mid(RandomString, 3, intLen * 2)`

Answer (score 3):

As @June7 correctly notes in their answer, the reason that your function does not return anything is because the symbol `KeyNo` is initialised as a null string (`""`) by virtue of the fact that the function is defined to return a string (`Function KeyNo` `...` **`As String`**), however, you don't redefine `KeyNo` to anything else within the function, hence, the function will always return an empty string.

---

However, for the task that you have described:

> I want to be able to update the field `RanKeyNo5` with the numeric equivalent (2 digits) for a specified number of letters as they occur in the `Ran` field.

The code could be greatly simplified - for example, consider the following approach:

```vb
Function KeyNo(strStr As String, intLen As Integer) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(strStr)
        a = Asc(Mid(strStr, i, 1)) - 64
        If a <= intLen Then KeyNo = KeyNo & Format(a, "00")
    Next i
End Function
```

```vb
?KeyNo("BFHCIEALGJDK",5)
0203050104
```